# Microsoft Visual C ++ Crash when Install qgis.2.8.1

Tags: qgis, installation, c++

[image: Runtime error]

I have installed and reinstalled QGIS ver.2.8.1. and always display a message as shown below. I hope someone can help me fix these problems.

Comment: When does this error appear? Which installer did you use? Did you run installation with admin privileges?

Comment: I have the same issue on a machine. My OS is win 7 64 and I have tried with the stand allone or OSGeo4w 64 bits installers. I know about this thread http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72506/how-to-fix-runtime-error-r6034-an-application-has-made-an-attempt-to-load-th-c and this one also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552348/runtime-error-r6034-in-embedded-python-application/14680947#14680947 but I have not been able to solve the issue

Comment: The error appear when start the qgis 2.8.1. I use OS W.8.1,32.