# QGIS runtime error R6034

Tags: qgis, runtimeerror

I get a runtime error R6034 every time I open QGIS. I am running under Windows 10 on a 64-bit machine.  This issue has been raised previously with answers that might be useful for a experienced system manager ([How to fix Runtime Error R6034: An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library incorrectly?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/72506/how-to-fix-runtime-error-r6034-an-application-has-made)).  However, I would like to recommend QGIS to high school students.

Is there any harm in continuing to run QGIS despite the runtime error?

Will proceeding lead to problems with QGIS or other software on my machine?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a permanent error, I am running on several Windows platforms and don't have it.

Cleaning up MS VC runtime DLLs would be a good idea, but this has to be done on every PC that complains about it.

BTW I suggest to use the latest version of QGIS. The runtime error might have been fixed already according to https://hub.qgis.org/issues/8629.

Comment: I installed QGIS Standalone Installer  Version 2.16 (64bit) from http://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html on 7/29/2016.  I get the runtime error everytime I start QGIS.  This is consistent with my experience over the last couple of years with earlier versions.  This has discouraged me from using QGIS or recommending it to others.  It occurs to me though that the problem might involve other 3rd party software on my machine.  I'll try to find another Windows 10 machine to try it out.

Comment: There might be a conflict with other software on your PC that has stored MS VC Runtimes before. If nothing helps, you could install a Virtual Box with some Ubuntu OS inside. QGIS runs fine on that platform too, and for sure no MS VC Runtime error will occur inside the box.

Answer (score 1):

As other coders find out, problem is in most cases caused by file msvcr90.dll, placed in windows/system32 directory by installation of certain 32-bit program. 64-bit QGIS placed its own proper version (with the same name) into WinSXS, but paths to system32 is higher in a list of paths to libraries so QGIS tries to pick wrong 32-bit version first, generating r6034 error. For my needs I simply removed file from system32 directory and QGIS stopped exhibit annoying error. All other apps after few weeks still works fine ... - just my 2 plain user cents :)